# Linux command-line utils with built-in support of multithreading

Tags: linux, command-line, multi-core, parallel-processing, smp

I would like to be able to compare performance of multicore computers from a point of view of a user who performs typical day-to-day tasks in Linux. My current goal is to collect a list of compute intensive open-source command-line utilities that have built-in support of multithreading.

By searching with `man -K 1`, `apropos`, `yum search all`, `zypper search -d` for "*parallel*", "*processor*", "*thread*", I identified the following applications that satisfy my needs: `pbzip2 -p#`, `pigz -p #`, `pixz -p #`, `sort --parallel=#`, `xz -T #`.

Of course, one can also utilize multicore systems by running sequential applications in background or utilizing pipes, GNU `parallel`, `tee`, `xargs -P #`. I am also aware of `make -j #` that is used to speed up building.

Does anybody know any other compute intensive open-source Linux CLI utils that could exploit multicore processors?

As I'm primarily interested in utils that could be installed from vendor-supplied repos, "non-standard" utils are also welcomed.